# Applying .slider to hidden divs

Tags: jquery, css

this is kinda tricky to explain,but here goes....I have multiple hidden divs that swap with one another when clicking a link using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
  });
});
```

I have also made a slider function which works great, but when the div changes the slider will not work. How can I get it to target the hidden div when they are called up? I assume its a variable thing?

this is my slider code

```
$(function() {
var scrollPane = $('#info'),
    scrollableHeight = scrollPane.height() - scrollPane.parent().height() || 0;

$("#slider-vertical").slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "max",
  min: 0,
  max: scrollableHeight,
  value: scrollableHeight,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    scrollPane.css({top: ui.value - scrollableHeight});
  }
});
```

});

here is a working example to better understand.....please excuse the messy code

http://www.kerrydean.ca/tizzest.html#

thanks in advance

Comment: I do not get it, the example has a working example.. copy past it? I don't see which effect your trying to accomplish. But if your updating certain elements and you want to make the new elements have the same effects / events / actions whatever try look at the jquery live function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider is only set to scroll the #info div when you set `var scrollPane`, and not your other two divs (#info2 and #info3). Instead give your all sliding divs a shared class, such as `class="info"` and set `scrollPane` like so:

```
var scrollPane = $('.info'),
    scrollableHeight = scrollPane.height() - scrollPane.parent().height() || 0;
```

Then make sure you set your slider to a default position when showing/hiding your divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");

    // Reset slider to top
    var max = $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max);
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", max);
  });
});
```

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to accept your answers so people will answer more of your questions in the future.

Comment: Actually sorry.. one glitch. Works great with the exception that when the slider resets to the top, the div its controlling for some reason does not start at the top, but a few increments down. Any idea on what might cause this? Thank you again for your time and knowledge

Comment: It's just that the div's position never changes when swapping views. Try adding something like `$(".info").css("top", 0)` to your `click` function.

Comment: I'm back..... Sorry If Im getting annoying....Im having one last trouble. Everything is now working great, but when the div changes, it seems to only scroll the length of the previous 1st div. Can I reset it so it scrolls the full lenght of each div?

Comment: Can't say based on your information. You'll probably want to make a new question with your current code since it sounds like it's changed quite a bit, and your demo site appears to work correctly.